# subclass elements from an arraylist won't use the overriden method in Java

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, subclass, overriding

I have an ArrayList with a certain class (Piece) from which I want to pick items with a subclass (Miner and Bomb). However, when I pick some items it will use the methods of the super class (Piece), and not it's subclasses.

Since `ArrayList<Pieces>` will contain several subclass objects of pieces, it is not possible to define a more specific class for ArrayList. Is it possible to pick some elements from ArrayList and still use the methods from the subclasses?

(I found it a little hard to find the solution for this simple problem. I searched for overriding, arrayList, methods along some other things, but couldn't find it. If it was too obvious to found, I'd like to know where you found it.)

Class Main:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Piece> pieceList = new ArrayList<>();
        pieceList.add(new Miner());
        pieceList.add(new Bomb());

        // create new classes to test canDefeat
        if (new Miner().canDefeat(new Bomb())) {
            System.out.println("Yes! This line will be printed.");
        }

        System.out.println();

        // test canDefeat with pieces from the pieceList
        if (pieceList.get(0).canDefeat(pieceList.get(1))) {
               System.out.println("No, this line will not be printed");
        }

    }
}
```

Class Piece:

```
public abstract class Piece {

    public boolean canDefeat(Piece opponent) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Class Miner:

```
public class Miner extends Piece {

    public boolean canDefeat(Bomb opponent) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Class Bomb:

```
public class Bomb extends Piece {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The *why* of this is easy:

1. Your `Miner` doesn't override `canDefeat(Piece)`, it adds a *new* method with the signature `canDefeat(Bomb)`.
2. In the code `pieceList.get(0).canDefeat(pieceList.get(1))`, all the compiler has to work with is the type `Piece`, and so it resolves that to `Piece#canDefeat(Piece)`.

The *what to do instead* is more tricky.

I would suggest that what kinds of pieces can defeat what other kinds of pieces isn't an attribute of each piece; for one thing, that will get brittle fairly quickly if you change the rules.

Instead, I would look at alternatives like:

- Perhaps each piece can have a strength level, where higher strength means the piece can defeat a piece with lower strength. (Example below.)
- You could have a `BattleLogic` class that can compare types of pieces to determine the outcome, which would either work with strength per the above, or by type using `instanceof`, etc. Normally, when you reach for `instanceof` you need to stop and think about what you're doing and whether it's really the right tool for the job (it usually isn't), but it may well be the right tool for *this* job. The advantage to a `BattleLogic` class is that none of the pieces knows anything about the other pieces; instead, you have one thing that understands the game as a whole and how the pieces rank when they fight. (Example below.)

**If** you want each `Piece` to know what other types of pieces it can defeat, you *can* do that, but I think it will tend to lead to an unmaintainable mess. Two ways come to mind:

- Having a list of the types it can defeat. (Example below.)
- Using reflection to achieve what you were trying to do originally. (Example below.)

Here's the strength suggestion in code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Piece {

    private int strength;

    public Piece(int strength) {
        this.strength = strength;
    }

    public int getStrength() {
        return this.strength;
    }

    public boolean canDefeat(Piece opponent) {
        return this.getStrength() > opponent.getStrength();
    }
}

class Miner extends Piece {

    public Miner() {
        super(10);
    }
}

class Bomb extends Piece {
    public Bomb() {
        super(5);
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Piece> pieceList = new ArrayList<>();
        pieceList.add(new Miner());
        pieceList.add(new Bomb());

        // create new classes to test canDefeat
        if (new Miner().canDefeat(new Bomb())) {
            System.out.println("Yes! This line will be printed.");
        }

        System.out.println();

        // test canDefeat with pieces from the pieceList
        if (pieceList.get(0).canDefeat(pieceList.get(1))) {
            System.out.println("Yes! This line will also be printed");
        }

    }
}
```

And the `BattleLogic` suggestion in code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

abstract class Piece {
}

class Miner extends Piece {
}

class Bomb extends Piece {
}

class BattleLogic {

    /**
     * Does a battle between the two pieces.
     *
     * @param   a   The first piece
     * @param   b   The second piece
     * @return  0 for a tie, a negative number if a beats b, or a positive number if b beats a
     */
    public static int battle(Piece a, Piece b) {
        if (a instanceof Miner && b instanceof Bomb) {
            return -1;
        }
        // ...further tests here...
        return 0;
    }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Piece> pieceList = new ArrayList<>();
        pieceList.add(new Miner());
        pieceList.add(new Bomb());

        // create new classes to test canDefeat
        if (BattleLogic.battle(new Miner(), new Bomb()) < 0) {
            System.out.println("Yes! This line will be printed.");
        }

        System.out.println();

        // test canDefeat with pieces from the pieceList
        if (BattleLogic.battle(pieceList.get(0), pieceList.get(1)) < 0) {
            System.out.println("Yes! This line will also be printed");
        }

    }
}
```

Here's that third suggestion, having each type of piece know what pieces it can defeat, in case. Again, though, I don't suggest this; I think having the pieces know this much about each other is going to be a maintenance problem:

```
// Not really recommended
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

abstract class Piece {
    private List<Class> iDefeat;

    public Piece(Class... defeats) {
        this.iDefeat = new ArrayList<Class>();
        for (Class c : defeats) {
            this.iDefeat.add(c);
        }
    }

    public boolean canDefeat(Piece piece) {
        return this.iDefeat.contains(piece.getClass());
    }
}

class Bomb extends Piece {
}

class Miner extends Piece {

    public Miner() {
        super(Bomb.class);
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Piece> pieceList = new ArrayList<>();
        pieceList.add(new Miner());
        pieceList.add(new Bomb());

        // create new classes to test canDefeat
        if (new Miner().canDefeat(new Bomb())) {
            System.out.println("Yes! This line will be printed.");
        }

        System.out.println();

        // test canDefeat with pieces from the pieceList
        if (pieceList.get(0).canDefeat(pieceList.get(1))) {
            System.out.println("Yes! This line will also be printed");
        }

    }
}
```

Or you could make the list static if you're going to have millions of pieces and memory is an issue; this is just a sketch.

And finally, the way using reflection:

```
// Not reall recommended
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Piece {

    public Piece() {
    }

    private static Method getMethodOrNull(Class cls, String name, Class... paramTypes) {
        try {
            return cls.getMethod(name, paramTypes);
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public boolean canDefeat(Piece opponent) {
        try {
            Class thisClass = this.getClass();
            Class oppClass = opponent.getClass();
            Method m = null;

            while (oppClass != Piece.class && (m = getMethodOrNull(thisClass, "canDefeat", oppClass)) == null) {
                oppClass = oppClass.getSuperclass();
            }
            if (m != null) {
                return (boolean)m.invoke(this, opponent);
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception iae) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't access method", iae);
        }
    }
}

class Miner extends Piece {

    public boolean canDefeat(Bomb b) {
        return true;
    }

}

class Bomb extends Piece {
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Piece> pieceList = new ArrayList<>();
        pieceList.add(new Miner());
        pieceList.add(new Bomb());

        // create new classes to test canDefeat
        if (new Miner().canDefeat(new Bomb())) {
            System.out.println("Yes! This line will be printed.");
        }

        System.out.println();

        // test canDefeat with pieces from the pieceList
        if (pieceList.get(0).canDefeat(pieceList.get(1))) {
            System.out.println("Yes! This line will also be printed");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. I would rather not like to use `instanceof`, because our teacher really doesn't like that ;)
We use already strength() for all other pieces, but the combination Miner - Bomb is rather an exception, so that's why I wanted to add a method for this exception. Now, I use `if (opponent.getPieceName() == "Bomb") return true;` within the Miner class, but of course it is more or less the same as `instanceof`. I will reconsider your solutions the coming days.

Comment: `(opponent.getPieceName() == "Bomb")` is not much better than `instanceof`.  At least consider using enum or some constants in this case.  And you know that you shouldn't do string comparison using `==` in Java right?

Comment: @Hoboist: ^^ What Adrian said, both about `getPieceName` and about comparing strings. :-) Also, I've added a fourth option using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

`Miner` does not override the `canDefeat`-method of `Piece` because the parameter type is narrowed. You can check this easily by adding

```
@Override
```

to the method you think you are overriding to verify it at compile time.

Furthermore, it is not good OO style to provide default behavior in abstract super classes but rather move the behavior into concrete children where possible because otherwise you may involuntary inherit behavior you otherwise would like to overwrite. In your case, make `canDefeat` abstract and let `Bomb` implement it with the behavior currently present in `Piece`.

Comment: *"In your case, make `canDefeat` abstract and let `Bomb` implement it with the behavior currently present in `Piece`."* That just begs the question, though, doesn't it? *How* would they do that? Without resorting to code smells like `instanceof`...

Comment: As Java does not support multi methods I would invert the control where `canDefeat` does nothing but call something like `opponent.isDefeatableBy(this);` for every sub class of `Piece` which requires each an implementation of `isDefeatableBy` for every sub class of `Piece` but where the behavior can be clearly specified for each combination of enemies.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the signature of `canDefeat` to accept generic types, and make sure you do the overriding in the right way, both signatures are always the same

**Piece** class

```
public abstract class Piece {

    public boolean canDefeat(Piece opponent) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Miner** class

```
public class Miner extends Piece {

    @Override
    public boolean canDefeat(Piece opponent) { // Piece not Bomb
        return true;
    }

}
```

> Update to let `Miner` defeats only `Bomb`

**Piece** class

```
public abstract class Piece<T> {

    public boolean canDefeat(T opponent) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Miner** class

```
public class Miner extends Piece<Bomb> {

    @Override
    public boolean canDefeat(Bomb opponent) { // Defeats Bomb
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: But that would mean `Miner` can defeat **all** `Piece`s, which presumably isn't the case.

Comment: Now, it defeats only `Bomb`s

Comment: And as soon as there's another kind of piece, which `Miner`s can't defeat, you're stuffed. :-) Unless you're going to add a parameter for every kind of piece out there, which means `Miner` knows **far** too much about the other pieces (and by extension, all the other pieces know far too much about each other), turning into an unmaintainable mess.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer. However, isn't Miner now only usable for opponents which is of type Bomb? I'd rather like to be able to use the Miner class for all opponent. Still, thank you for the solution with generics: by the example I understand generics a little more.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the proper answer of @T.J. Crowder I would recommend you to also think about implementing this whole stuff within a more data-oriented approach instead of an object-oriented one. This looks like a perfect problem that can be implemented within an Entity-System framework (like ["Artemis"](https://code.google.com/p/artemis-framework/)) where your Piece is an entity having a strength component and the whole logic goes to a BattleSystem.

Such an approach is height adaptable on changing rules. For example, if your defeat is not only related to strength but also to health it is easy to add also a health parameter to the strength-component or even create a additional health component and the logic in the BattleSystem can than deal with it.
The more difficult thing within this approach is the right design of entities and component and systems and the inter-system communication for your specific needs.

read more about Entity-Component-Systems also here: 
[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system) : 
[Artemis](https://github.com/junkdog/artemis-odb/wiki/Introduction-to-Entity-Systems)

Comment: nice idea! I will think about that.